# Did Pythagoras exist?

Tags: biographical-details, ancient-greece

My history of maths lecturer claims Pythagoras never existed. Is this true? Is there any evidence he existed? He also claims the Pythagoreans did not discover or prove the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: You should post question about the history of science and mathematics on our main site: [hsm.se]. The meta-HSM site that you're currently posting on is exclusively reserved for discussions about the site (so-called meta-discussions). I'll move these questions to the main site for you, but please ask them there directly in the future.